# libGL.so.1 missing on Amazon Linux 2022

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are trying to execute a python program from e2 instance . but we are getting the below error.

Attaching the error .

```
sh-4.2$ python3 Landing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Landing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help on this issue?

Comment: You need to install Mesa or whatever OpenGL-supporting package is available for your distribution. What OS is your EC2 instance running?

Comment: We are using  Linux/UNIX (Inferred)

Comment: Okay, what distribution/release? CentOS? Debian? FreeBSD? Ubuntu? Amazon Linux? etc.

Comment: we are using Amazon Linux 2-GI-Non-CIO-07May2022

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Amazon Linux 2, you need to install `libglvnd-glx` in order to get the `libGL.so.1` library.

```
yum update
yum install libglvnd-glx
```

```
# and now libGL.so.1 exists
bash-5.1# ls -l /lib64/libGL.*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      14 Oct 22  2021 /lib64/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.7.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1000048 Oct 22  2021 /lib64/libGL.so.1.7.0
```

Comment: Any idea how can we fix this error to.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package

Comment: @Sidh You'll need to build and install the Snowflake connector on your instance, since apparently Snowflake don't have a package on PyPI: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python - the README has the directions. Additional info here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#python-packages